# through [year] to

Tags: meaning-in-context

https://www.cnbc.com/2019/01/21/china-2018-gdp-china-reports-economic-growth-for-fourth-quarter-year.html

> China pegged its proposal to buy more U.S. goods **through** 2024 **to**
>   President Donald Trump’s hopes of being re-elected in 2020, the
>   sources told CNBC.

What does "through 2024" mean? What does "to ... Trump's hopes" mean?

Comment: My guess is "through [year]" means "until and including [year]", but I'm a non-native speaker and I'm here because I neither really know what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tbh, that sentence is confusing to me as a native speaker.

But I'm pretty sure it is supposed to be parsed as

> China pegged (its proposal to buy more U.S. goods through 2024) to President Donald Trump’s hopes of being re-elected in 2020, the sources told CNBC.

That is,

> China pegged ____ to ____, ...

tbh, I'm not sure exactly what is meant by "pegged" here. I don't read much news.

And the use of the word "through" like that is unusual.

Answer (score 1):

Through Means throughout, so throughout 2024.

To Trumps hopes means he hopes he will get re-elected, so China want to buy goods.

Comment: Not just throughout 2024, but continuously from now until 2024.